# Не удается поменять местами расположение элементов в wordpress woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Приветствую. В файле wc-template-hooks.php
есть записи:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
```

Хочу поменять расположение местами элементов для чего меняю позиции 20 с 30 вот так

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 20 );
```

но, не выходит..

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно в файле fonctions.php темы, или в своем модуле сделать такое:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
```

Это отключит стандартные хуки.
Теперь ниже вы смело можите их опять добавить, только с нужным приоритетом:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 20 );
```

Comment: не все так просто - переопределение было глубже - в конфиге самой темы. вопрос снят